# Accumulated jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am using [Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/events.html#render) to load contents via ajax (3 posts every new load, which each posts have "button").

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
  $(function () {       
    'use strict';
    alert('1. Initial load');

    jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {           
        Rh_function();          
    }); 

    alert ('End');      
}); 
})(jQuery, this);

function Rh_function()
{
    jQuery('.button').click(function(e) {       
    alert('Button is clicked ');            
    });
}
```

1. Initial page load (3 posts: A, B, C):

   I get the following alerts right away:

   ```
   "1. Initial load"

   "End"
   ```

   If I click the button in the post-A, then, I get "Button is clicked" alert
2. Next set of posts are loaded (6 posts: A, B, C, D, E, F)
   I get following alerts when I click buttons:

   ```
   Post-A(1st load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-B(1st load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-C(1st load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-D(2nd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-E(2nd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-F(2nd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
   ```

Note that the initial loads now shows two alerts

3. Third set of posts are loaded (9 posts: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)
   I get following alerts when I click buttons:

   ```
   Post-A(1st load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-B(1st load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-C(1st load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-D(2nd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-E(2nd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-F(2nd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-G(3rd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-H(3rd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
   Post-I(3rd load): 
           "Button is clicked"
   ```

Note that the 1st load now shows three alerts, 2 load with two alerts.

I am not sure what is going on.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're binding the events without care that a given object already has the event bound, so the click gets fired off once for each time you've bound the event.

That is, this:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function(e) { });
```

Doesn't care if the event was already bound, it will bind a new copy.

I would need to check if `jQuery('.button').click(someFunc);` would also fire multiple times (I believe so).  So my suggestion would be to either:

a) add a class to the button when the event is bound, then ignore objects with that class.

b) add a class to the button when it is created, then *remove it* when the event is bound.

Edit:

Based on the comment from @Stryner, a better solution would be to use the `items` array passed by `ias()`, eg:

```
jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {           
    jquery.each(items,function(i, val) {
        val.click(function(e) {       
            alert('Button is clicked ');            
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Another suggestion would be to use `items` which is provided by IAS.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That would also work.  That would in fact be the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I am bit confused to how to use the `items`. Can you show me one simple example? thanks

Comment: See edited answer.  I *think* I got the jquery correct.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try!

Comment: Don't forget to up/down/accept the answer (as necessary). :)